# Changing output stream back to system.out

Tags: java, io, system.out

My main calls several classes, each of which redirects System.out so they can intercept what was **printed** by another class (even if this is bad practice - I have to do this).
Then, after they all finish, I would like to simply print on the screen with my main, but nothing happens.

Code in class1, class2:

```
doStuff() {
   ByteArrayOutputStream outContent = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
   System.setOut(new PrintStream(outContent));
   ...
```

Main:

```
class1.doStuff();
class2.doStuff();
...
System.setOut(System.out); //set output back
System.out.println("Success!"); //print something. doesn't work!
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to save the original `System.out` somewhere.
`System.setOut()` modifies `System.out`, so you're essentially doing `System.out = System.out;` which of course does nothing.

Comment: Thank you, this worked. I was thinking System.out is the default stream, not the one which is being used currently!